Modificar caminho de acesso para Views e wwwRoot ASPNET MVC
Criei uma solution onde possui uma pasta src e dentro desta pasta há outras duas, Backend e Web.

Na pasta Backend eu criei um projeto AspNet MVC, onde, por padrão, vieram pastas como Controller, Views e wwwroot.
Na pasta Web eu criei um Class Library inicialmente vazia

imagem ilustrativa https://i.sstatic.net/TMiTzvJj.png
Após a criação de ambos, eu movi as pastas Views e wwwRoot (com seus arquivos padrões) para dentro da ClassLibrary, portanto o projeto AspNet MVC ficou apenas com a controller.
No entanto, ao executar o projeto MVC, deparo-me com o erro

"InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"

imagem ilustrativa https://i.sstatic.net/fzC8I5p6.png
Classe program:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Creio que, ao mover os arquivos, a busca padrão nos diretórios foi prejudicada. Como isso pode ser solucionado?

Por que você fez isso?

Você inverteu a lógica de funcionamento do ASP.NET MVC. A controller funciona como uma ponte para o back-end. Tudo o que você fez foi desmembrar um projeto MVC.
Geralmente mantemos um projeto ASP.NET MVC com todas as suas controllers e views, daí você pode criar um projeto de biblioteca de classes para manter suas entidades, outro contendo apenas a parte de acesso a dados, e assim por diante. Seguindo a lógica, nas suas controllers você injeta os seus gerenciadores, repositórios ou serviços.
Você pode verificar mais detalhes em:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
